# Not using the hostname and port in jdbc url

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have some application connecting to Oracle database through SpringJDBC as well as plain JDBC.

JDBC URL pattern is -

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portNumber/schemaName
```

We are trying to create a TNS entry which can be related with the application. For example if there is an application StockTrade then the schema name will be DBStockTrade.

However developers still need to know the hostname and port number for construction of JDBC URL and need to make binary change whenever the schema name is changed.

Is there a way to avoid using the hostname and port number and simply use the schema name for connecting to the database? The idea is to use some kind of property file containing the schema name only and get rid of other details.

Comment: Why not to use jndi lookup?

Comment: Are these client/ server applications that are deployed to a large number of clients?  Or three-tier applications deployed to a relatively small number of application servers?  You could do something like use Oracle Internet Directory (OID) to store all your TNS information centrally and just use a static TNS alias in your application.  But that would generally make more sense in a client/ server world where there are large numbers of client applications than in a three-tier world where there are a small number of identically configured app servers.

Comment: could you try jdbc url

 jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portNumber:Database_Name


I'm using my project in this way and not cause problems.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukKurt - how does that remove the dependency on the hostname and port? You're just using the SID instead of the service name?

Comment: Externalize the config in a property file, or in JNDI and you don't need to make a "binary change".

Answer (score 1):

For the issue:

> need to make binary change whenever the schema name is changed

We can simply **put the JDBC URL into a configuration file**

Then whenever the schema name changed, we only need to edit the configuration file and no binary change needed.

For example, save the JDBC URL to a **.properties** file

```
# config.properties

jdbc_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portNumber/schemaName
```

In the Java code:

```
String currentPath = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
    .getLocation().toURI().getPath();
String configFile = currentPath + File.separator + "config.properties";
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));
String jdbcUrl = prop.getProperty("jdbc_url")
```

So with the `jdbcUrl` we can connect to the database